# Java: Pig Game becoming endless loop?

Tags: java

So my programming class has this assignment where the player and computer play the game of Pig up to 50 points, and that multiple classes are used to roll the Dice. The computer can play up until 20 points for a turn, and the player is prompted to enter y or n to continue rolling or not. If any die is rolled as 1, all points for that round are lost.

However, the game becomes an endless loop using while, and I'm not sure exactly why. I'm fairly new to java so I'm not sure how else to phrase this.

Die class

```
    public class Die {

    private final int MAX = 6; //maximum face value
    private int faceValue; //current value showing on the die

    public Die() {
        //Constuctor: Sets the initial face value
        faceValue = 1;

    }

    public int roll() {
        //Rolls the die and returns the result
        faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;
        return faceValue;

    }

    public void setFaceValue(int value) {
        //Face value mutator
        faceValue = value;

    }

    public int getFaceValue() {
        //Face value accessor
        return faceValue;

    }

    public String toString() {
        //Returns a string representation of this die.
        String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);
        return result;

    }
}
```

PairOfDice class

```
public class PairOfDice {
    //Creates two Die objects
    Die die1 = new Die();
    Die die2 = new Die();

    private int faceValue1;
    private int faceValue2;

    //Initialize sum variable as an integer
    int sum;

    public int getDie1() {
        //Get value of first die
        faceValue1 = die1.getFaceValue();
        return faceValue1;
    }

    public int getDie2() {
        //Get value of second die
        faceValue2 = die2.getFaceValue();
        return faceValue2;
    }

    public void setDie1(int value) {
        //Set value of first die
        die1.setFaceValue(1);
    }

    public void setDie2(int value2) {
        //Set value of second die
        die2.setFaceValue(1);
    }

    public int sumDice() {
        //Adds values of both dice into a sum
        sum = die1.getFaceValue() + die2.getFaceValue();
        return sum;
    }

    public int rollDice() {
        //Rolls both dice and returns results
        int roll = die1.roll() + die2.roll();
        return roll;
    }

    public String toString() {
        //Returns a string representation of the dice
        String result = Integer.toString(sum);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Pig class / Hog class (my professor calls it the Hog game fyi)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Hog {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Declaring data variables
            char answer = 'n';
            PairOfDice dice;
            Die die1;
            Die die2;

            Scanner playerAnswer = new Scanner(System.in);

            dice = new PairOfDice();
            die1 = new Die();
            die2 = new Die();

            int computerTotalScore = 0;
            int humanTotalScore = 0;

            int computerRoundTotal;
            int humanRoundTotal;

            int die1FaceValue = 0;
            int die2FaceValue = 0;

            //Main loop of the game
            while (computerTotalScore < 50 && humanTotalScore < 50) {
                //The computer's turn
                computerRoundTotal = 0; //resetting for computer's next turn

                System.out.println("Current Status: ");
                System.out.println("Computer: " + computerTotalScore);
                System.out.println("You: " + humanTotalScore);

                while (computerRoundTotal < 20 && (die1FaceValue > 1 && die2FaceValue > 1)) {
                   die1.roll();
                   die2.roll();

                   die1FaceValue = die1.getFaceValue();
                   die2FaceValue = die2.getFaceValue();

                   System.out.println("Die 1: " + die1FaceValue + ", Die 2: " + die2FaceValue);

                   computerRoundTotal = computerRoundTotal + (die1FaceValue + die2FaceValue);
                   System.out.println("Current Round: " + computerRoundTotal);
                }

                if (die1FaceValue == 1 || die2FaceValue == 1) {
                   System.out.println("Busted!");
                }
                  else {
                     computerTotalScore = computerTotalScore + computerRoundTotal;
                  }

                //Player's turn
                humanRoundTotal = 0; //resetting for player's next turn

                System.out.println("Current Status: ");
                System.out.println("Computer: " + computerTotalScore);
                System.out.println("You: " + humanTotalScore);

                while (answer != 'y' && (die1FaceValue > 1 || die2FaceValue > 1)) {
                    die1.roll();
                    die2.roll();

                    die1FaceValue = die1.getFaceValue();
                    die2FaceValue = die2.getFaceValue();

                    System.out.println("Die 1: " + die1FaceValue + ", Die 2: " + die2FaceValue);

                    humanRoundTotal = humanRoundTotal + (die1FaceValue + die2FaceValue);
                    System.out.println("Current Round: " + humanRoundTotal);

                    System.out.println("Take another turn (y/n)?");
                    answer = playerAnswer.next().charAt(0);
                }

                if (die1FaceValue == 1 || die2FaceValue == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Busted!");
                }
                  else {
                      humanTotalScore = humanTotalScore + humanRoundTotal;
                  }
            }

            if (computerTotalScore >= 50) {
                System.out.println("The computer has won!");
            }
              else {
                  System.out.println("You won!");
              }

            System.out.println("Final Results:");
            System.out.println("Computer: " + computerTotalScore);
            System.out.println("You: " + humanTotalScore);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and specifically [mcve] and http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Where it becomes an endless loop? Please rewrite your code to meet the requirements for it to become a [mcve]

Comment: You never use `PairOfDice`; As it is now there's no need to include it in your question at all.  Are you supposed to be using it?  Hint #2:  Your while loop `while (answer != 'y' && (die1FaceValue > 1 || die2FaceValue > 1))` never runs because `die1FaceValue` and `die2FaceValue` are initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't debugged your whole code, but the reason for your endless loop is due to `die1FaceValue` and `die2FaceValue` being initialized with `0`. Now the boolean expression `computerRoundTotal < 20 && (die1FaceValue > 1 && die2FaceValue > 1)` (this also applies to the players round) will always be `false` since `die1FaceValue == 0` and `die2FaceValue == 0`. To quickly fix this problem you could add an if-case to your while loop as follows

```
 while (computerRoundTotal < 20) {
   //roll your dice here

   if(die1FaceValue == 1 || die2FaceValue == 1){
     //reset points here and break, since the computers turn is over
     break;

   }
   //implement the "normal" turn logic here

}
```

Hope this helps in order to fix your program. Note that I haven't checked your code for further errors.

Also you check whether `answer != 'y'`. I don't know if this is intended or not, but the player will only continue rolling if he inputs `'n'` (I'm assuming y stands for yes and n for no). So `answer == 'y'` would definitely be the more *appropriate* choice.